# Ethereum in space?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

Is there a list of missions that have flown to space that have broadcasted the Ethereum network to ground? I'm interested to know the feasibility of this project and would like to start by surveying if there have been experiments in this area or not.

Answer (score 3):

I found some information from a couple years back, they got a three year grant so maybe an update will be coming soon:

> A research project funded and co-run by NASA is looking to leverage the Ethereum blockchain’s smart contracts technology to automate spacecraft maneuvering while avoiding space debris. In developments that could potentially have significant implications for deep space probes, NASA is putting resources behind a research…

https://www.ccn.com/nasa-researches-ethereum-blockchain-tech-for-deep-space-exploration/

Comment: It doesn’t appear that project has progressed as planned. Searching for the project or it’s owner’s name doesn’t produce any result. One might say right now it’s still at the end of the planned project period so no outcome has been published yet. But it doesn’t sound likely to have no intermediate outcomes. My suspicion is that the project was among those spawned during the crypto hype of 2017/2018. And most likely they have already changed course. From an engineering point of view, the blockchain element sounds counterproductive in their settings.